# Angular Async-Await how to access Array Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

In Angular 7, I retrieved a list of Car from a remote  Service and then I want to iterate on this list after the HTTP-GET call is completed.
When I debug, I see the list of Cars but I cant access any of them. If I print the size of my list, it tells UNDEFINED.

How can I access the element in my list ? 
my Code:

```
private async search(attribute: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const someCars: Car[] = await this.searchService(attribute).toPromise();
    console.info(someCars.length); // --> length is undefined even if I can see all the elements in my list when I debug
    for (const car of someCars) { // --> undefined
      // print car
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("not found");
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: For troubleshooting, if you instead use a standard, non-async function and `subscribe()` to the `Observable<Car[]>` instead of `toPromise()` are you able to access the array of cars? Also are you sure that `this.searchService(attribute)` directly returns an array, or is it an object that has a nested property for that car array value?

Comment: DId you try using Postman or Swagger to first verify whether you service call works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander suggested, could it be an object {} that you get from API rather than an array []?

If it is the case, common approach to get the length of an object is to check the length of the keys:

```
Object.keys(someCars).length
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, Thanks! It was an object containing a list and not directly a list... oops